# Closing windows with middle mouse button under Ubuntu Mate

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I recently switched from `Linux Mint` to `Ubuntu Mate`. The former allowed to use the middle mouse button to close a window by clicking on its tab at the bottom, the latter doesn't. As it is a feature which I found rather handy I wanted to ask if there is a way to enable middle mouse-botton window closing under `Ubuntu Mate`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It's not possible in Ubuntu's distribution of MATE. I think, it was a customization of mint systems.

Because the settings key that allowed this was `org.mate.Marco.general action-middle-click-titlebar` and it's possible valid values in Ubuntu MATE are

```
$ gsettings range org.mate.Marco.general action-middle-click-titlebar 
enum
'toggle_shade'
'toggle_maximize'
'toggle_maximize_horizontally'
'toggle_maximize_vertically'
'minimize'
'none'
'lower'
'menu'
'last'
```

There is no close option. You can `shade`, `minimize`, `maximize` and several other window manipulations, but it seems `close` is not one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Too bad that it is not possible but I think I'll be able to live with it :)